# How can I stretch my navigation and content area height to 100% in CSS?

Tags: css, html, height

If you go to http://ffmages.com/final-fantasy-tactics (as an example), you will notice that the footer section shows behind both the navigation and content areas. I would like to make it so that the nav and content stretches at 100% height and the footer stays at the bottom of the screen.

The following is the CSS I am using for my header, menu, content, and footer sections:

```
#container {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(/images/background.gif); 
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#header {
    width: 1000px; 
    height: 98px;
    background-image: url(/images/header.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#primary {
    float: left; 
    width: 167px;
    height: 798px;
    text-align: left;
    padding-bottom: 14px;
    background-image: url(/images/nav-bg.jpg); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0px;
    border-top: 1px #000000 solid;
    border-left: 1px #000000 solid;
    border-right: 1px #000000 solid;
}

#content {
    float: right;
    width: 810px; 
    height: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #FFFFFF; 
    border-top: 1px #000000 solid; 
    border-right: 1px #000000 solid; 
    padding: 10px;
    line-height: 1.5em; 
    margin: 0px;
}

#footer {
    clear: both;
    width: 998px;
    height: 18px;
    font-size: 7pt;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #07162A;
    background-image: url(/images/footer-bg.jpg);
    border-top: 1px #000000 solid;
    border-left: 1px #000000 solid;
    border-right: 1px #000000 solid;
    border-bottom: 1px #000000 solid;
    padding-top: 6px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What is your HTML? Can you make a JSFiddle?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with JSFiddle. How do you create one?

Comment: [JSFiddle.net](http://www.jsfiddle.net/). Put your HTML in the top-left, your CSS in the top-right, and click "run". Bottom-right will show the output. Click "save" and post the URL.

Comment: Does http://jsfiddle.net/LNbfa/ work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say without seeing a div hierarchy.

Just spitballing here, but you could setup the div structure as such.

```
---------------------------------------------
|                  HEADER                   |
---------------------------------------------
|      |                                    |
|      |                                    |
|      |                                    |
| NAV  |           BODY                     |
|      |                                    |
|      |                                    |
|      |                                    |
---------------------------------------------
|                  FOOTER                   |
---------------------------------------------
```

Where NAV is actually contained within BODY. When BODY or NAV expands vertically, FOOTER will be pushed accordingly. You'll have to play with margins and padding in order to get the footer to lay flush against the bottom of the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

All you should have to do (based on the example given is apply two attributes to your CSS

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
```

Once both of these are applied your footer should always be on the bottom of the page and be however wide you set it... In your case `998px`

Comment: That's not quite what I was hoping to do. This code makes the footer fixed and as you scroll, it stays there. I just wanted to ensure that the footer stays at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @OmarHachem are you wanting it at the bottom of the page or are you wanting it below the content?  If you are wanting it at the bottom of the page see my css changes.  If you are wanting it simply to always be below your content then see jskiles1 description of page layout. This would be laid out as... `<body><div id="header"></div><div id="content"><div id="nav"></div><div id="body"></div></div><div id="footer"></div></body>`